# Android Fragment: Different animations for enter and return

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, android-architecture-navigation

I'm showing a fragment using the androidx navigation architecture component.

The fragment is shown by an ArcMotion shared element transition, but the exit transition should be a simple slide down.

I'm showing the fragment the following way:

```
findNavController().navigate(
    EntriesFragmentDirections.actionEntriesFragmentToNewBookEntryFragment(
        bookEntryType = mEntriesViewPager.currentItem,
        enterTransition = R.transition.new_book_entry_enter,
        exitTransition = R.transition.new_book_entry_exit
    ),
    FragmentNavigatorExtras(fabEntriesNewBookEntry to getString(R.string.transition_new_book_entry_fragment))
)
```

And I apply the transitions in the fragment in `onCreate`:

```
sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(args.enterTransition)
exitTransition = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(args.exitTransition)
```

The enter transition is working well, but the exit transition is still the reversed enter transition.

The enter transition xml:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <transition
        class="at.guger.moneybook.ui.transition.MorphTransform"
        app:endColor="?colorSurface"
        app:endCornerRadius="@dimen/zero"
        app:startColor="?colorSecondary"
        app:startCornerRadius="@dimen/fabRadius" />

</transitionSet>
```

The exit transition xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <slide android:slideEdge="bottom" />

</transitionSet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to inflate the transitions in the fragment's `onCreate`:

```
private val args: NewBookEntryFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if (Utils.isLollipop() && args.enterTransition > 0 && args.exitTransition > 0) {
        sharedElementEnterTransition = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(args.enterTransition)
        sharedElementReturnTransition = null
        returnTransition = TransitionInflater.from(requireContext()).inflateTransition(args.exitTransition)
}
```

The navigation call looks the following way:

```
findNavController().navigate(
    EntriesFragmentDirections.actionEntriesFragmentToNewBookEntryFragment(
        bookEntryType = mEntriesViewPager.currentItem,
        enterTransition = R.transition.new_book_entry_enter,
        exitTransition = R.transition.new_book_entry_exit
    ),
    FragmentNavigatorExtras(fabEntriesNewBookEntry to getString(R.string.transition_new_book_entry_fragment))
)
```

new_book_entry_enter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <transition
        class="at.guger.moneybook.ui.transition.MorphTransform"
        app:endColor="?colorSurface"
        app:endCornerRadius="@dimen/zero"
        app:startColor="?colorSecondary"
        app:startCornerRadius="@dimen/fabRadius" />

</transitionSet>
```

new_book_entry_exit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

    <slide
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quint"
        android:slideEdge="bottom" />

</transitionSet>
```